# Number of Days Conversion in Java

Tags: java, days

I need to use the modulo operand to convert an inputted number of days to its equivalent number of year/s, month/s, week/s, and days. We just started discussion yesterday so I'm still a bit rusty but this is the program I made:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DaysConvert {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int noOfDays, year, month, week, days;

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Days: ");
    noOfDays = input.nextInt();

    year = noOfDays/365;
    month = year%365;
    week = month%30;
    days = week%7;

    System.out.println("Year: " + year);
    System.out.println("Month: " + month);
    System.out.println("Week: " + week);
    System.out.println("Day: " + days);
}
}
```

Is my algorithm wrong or something?

Comment: It is both "wrong" and "something".  Do you expect to be able to work out `month`, `week` and `days` based just on `year`?

Comment: what about leap year ?

Comment: And what about months with 31 days? Or 28? Better to use [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Even Joda can't do this.  The problem is not sufficiently well-defined.

Comment: @DavidWallace Agreed. Need to have a fixed instant.

Comment: Just use [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), specifically [periods](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_period.html).

Answer (score 4):

This will work properly:

```
year = (double) (noOfDays/365);

    month=noOfDays/30.41;

   week=noOfDays/7;
```

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going to a fixed `30 days` in a month `365 days` in a year with no leap year then you can iterate to the number of days in a for-loop and check the modulo of each one from the the user's inputted.

**sample:**

```
    for(int i = 1; i < noOfDays+1; i++)
    {
        if((i %30) == 0)
            month++;
        if((i%7) == 0)
            week++;
        if((i%365) == 0)
            ++year;
        if((i%1) == 0)
            days++;

    }

    System.out.println("Year: " + year);
    System.out.println("Month: " + month);
    System.out.println("Week: " + week);
    System.out.println("Days: " + days);
```

**result:**

```
Enter Number of Days: 330
Year: 0
Month: 11
Week: 47
Days: 330
```

Comment: Seriously?  I've heard of "division as iterated subtraction", but never "division as iterated modulo operator".

Comment: Yes I know it works.  Mowing the lawn with a pair of toenail clippers also works.  Why don't you just write `months = noOfDays / 30; weeks = noOfDays / 7; years = noOfDays / 365;` instead of re-inventing arithmetic operations?

Comment: @DavidWallace so you mean (30 days / 7) = (4 weeks)??? seems not right to me. integer is rounding it off.

Comment: Well, first you said your solution works.  Now you say it doesn't work.  Which is it?  Your solution gives `4` for the number of weeks in 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
public class DaysConvert
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int noOfDays, year, month, week, days;

        System.out.print("Enter Number of Days: ");
        noOfDays = input.nextInt();

        year = noOfDays/365;
        noOfDays=noOfDays%365;

        month = noOfDays/30;
        noOfDays=noOfDays%30;

        week = noOfDays/7;
        noOfDays=noOfDays%7;


        System.out.println("Year: " + year);
        System.out.println("Month: " + month);
        System.out.println("Week: " + week);
        System.out.println("Day: " + noOfDays);
    }
}
```